# My GLB model is not loading with A-Frame 1.0.0

Tags: aframe

My glTF model in a GLB file is not loading in A-Frame 1.0.0 and it used to work in A-Frame 0.9.2. I see the following error in console: `unexpected token g in JSON at position 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use A-Frame 1.0.3 or newer and make sure that your model load in the [gltf-viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)

Comment: I took a look at the current 1.0.0 docs and this information isn't there yet. Can you give an update and elaborate on the possible `response-type` values? https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/asset-management-system.html#specifying-response-type